# Dynamically load a child class?

Tags: java

I need to create instances of classes by class name, the problem is that these classes happen to be child classes(I already have an instance of the parent class). I remember class.forName() cannot load child class. In C++ I could use a look-up table from name to static function pointers to do this, but is this dynamic child class loading even possible in Java?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the answer, but it looks it doesn't work for the following example:

AbStractTest.java

```
public abstract class AbstractTest{
      AbstractTest(int i){}
      class InnerTest
      {
             InnerTest(){
                 System.out.println("inner test class");
             }
             void test(){
                 System.out.println("inner test");
             }
      }
}
```

Test.java

```
public class Test extends AbstractTest
{
      Test(int i){
          super(i);
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
      {
             Test t = new Test(1);
             AbstractTest.InnerTest innerTest = (AbstractTest.InnerTest)Class.forName("AbstractTest$InnerTest").getConstructor(AbstractTest.class).newInstance(t);
             innerTest.test();
      }
}
```

It ends up the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: AbstractTest$InnerTest.<init>(AbstractTest)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2678)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1629)
        at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

Comment: You sure `Class.forName()` doesn't work?

Comment: Which type of child class do you have? Is your inner class is qualified with static modifier or not?

Comment: It's failing because the Test constructor is not public.  See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, could you accept it please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated for question update**

getConstructor() returns only the public constructors.  You need to use getDeclaredConstructors() to get the other non-public constructors

This works:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class Test extends AbstractTest
{
      Test(int i){
          super(i);
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
      {
             Test t = new Test(1);
             final Constructor<?>[] constructors = Class.forName("AbstractTest$InnerTest").getDeclaredConstructors();
             Constructor<?> noArgConstructor = null;
             for (final Constructor<?> constructor : constructors)
             {
               if (constructor.getParameterTypes().length == 1)
                 noArgConstructor = constructor;
             }
             if (noArgConstructor == null)
               throw new RuntimeException("Failed to find no arg constructor");

             AbstractTest.InnerTest innerTest =  (AbstractTest.InnerTest) noArgConstructor.newInstance(t);

             innerTest.test();
      }
}

abstract class AbstractTest{
      AbstractTest(int i){}
      class InnerTest
      {
             InnerTest(){
                 System.out.println("inner test class");
             }
             void test(){
                 System.out.println("inner test");
             }
      }
}
```

Prints:

```
inner test class
inner test
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated to quickly.  Your actual problem is that the constructor is not public.